# To a database, what's 'restore'? What's 'recovery'?

Tags: database, restore, recovery

What's the difference of `restore` and `recovery`? What I understand is:

> restore: refresh a database using the
> backup files of this database
>
> recovery: after the database fail,
> such as the reboot the server, the
> database reapply the committed
> transaction in the transaction log

Does my understanding right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore; bring a file back from backup media, e.g. tape, other disk
Recovery; re-running or unwinding in progress transactions that were partly completed in the DB.

Generally one will recover and then restore.  Some RDBMes will hide the 2 different steps to some extent but still undertake the 2 different actions.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same function, bringing back records that were accidentally dropped, repair corrupted database files, restore entire tables as well as queries, forms, macros, and stored procedures.